# Customizing Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

In order to customize devise views I must access the devise folder which is unconviniently located at

```
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.5.2/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
```

I'd like the devise customization to be included in git and to take it where ever I take the code to (different pc, download from github etc)

How do I install devise to be in the app folder and not in the gems folder (which is specific for each computer I use)

If not possible, how should I work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Device [github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

> Since Devise is an engine, all its views are packaged inside the gem.
>   These views will help you get started, but after sometime you may want
>   to change them. If this is the case, you just need to invoke the
>   following generator, and it will copy all views to your application:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom devise gem to use on all your projects.

You can Fork the devise gem, and edit the view files on 
[Devise Default views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/views/devise/)

Then, you need to install your personal repository for devise in your other projects.

You can do it on your gemfile

`gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/andersonanderson/devise.git'`